# Flutter web - Privacy cookies consent banner

Tags: flutter, cookies, gdprconsentform

I use [stripe](https://stripe.com/en-gb-it) and google analytics in my flutter web app. I want to add a cookie consent banner according to GDPR regulations. I tried to use the library [Yett](https://github.com/elbywan/yett) as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69602063/6393618) stackoverflow post. But for this library to work I need to put it on top of all other third party libraries in my index.html file. But when I run my project, flutter puts all its dependencies at the top of index.html, before any libraries I had put in the file.

This way, the libraries load before the yett library. Is there a way to enforce yett library to be put before the rest of the dependencies injected my flutter or another way altogether to have cookies consent in flutter?